# Get Datatable to show all records without paging

Tags: datatables

For some reason when my datatable renders it will not show all records. I set the options as follows and am expecting the all option of -1 to show all records. But this says Showing 1 to 0 of 682,624 entries when I choose the All option.

I believe we are using DataTables v1.9

```
oDataTable = $('#dt_SubmissionOverview').dataTable({
"bServerSide": true,
"bStateSave": true,
"sAjaxSource": "/Submission/AjaxOverview",
"bProcessing": true,
"bDeferRender": true,
"sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
"bPaginate": true,
"pageLength": 99,
"bLengthChange": true,
"sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'lT><'span6'Gf>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
"iDisplayLength": 1000,
"oLanguage": {
    "sLengthMenu": 'Display <select>' +
    '<option value="10">10</option>' +
    '<option value="20">20</option>' +
    '<option value="30">30</option>' +
    '<option value="40">40</option>' +
    '<option value="50">50</option>' +
    '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
    '</select> records'
},
```

Comment: I have provided a solution. Accept my answer if it's resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

To change menu length use following syntax in your datatable

```
"aLengthMenu": [[10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]]
```

or

change following syntax which will work

```
"sLengthMenu": 'Display <select>'+
        '<option value="10">10</option>'+
        '<option value="20">20</option>'+
        '<option value="30">30</option>'+
        '<option value="40">40</option>'+
        '<option value="50">50</option>'+
        '<option value="-1">All</option>'+
        '</select> records'
```

and to find behavior of different properties check this link : https://legacy.datatables.net/ref